# Check in a series if there exists adjacent values with less than a certain number of missing values

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I'm working with a large number of series of different experiments, where there exist a lot of experiments where there are no entries.   I now want to draw a sample where there should exist at least 200 adjacent values of data with less than 100 entries of null (A 200 day period of complete data).

I started to do it with a loop, checking for 0-200, 1-200 for each dataset which takes ages... Should I use `Row / Scan/ Reap/ Sow`? I'd appreciate a help and guidance on possible functions I can use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $p_k$ with $1\leq k\leq N_0$ is the position of the $k$-th zero in the data list $\{a_1,\ldots,a_N\}$, then each sublist which contains $\leq M$ zeros will be a sublist of one of the sublists
$$
\{ a_{p_k+1},\ldots, a_{p_{k+M+2}-1}\}, \qquad 1\leq k \leq N_{0}-M-2
$$ 
or $\{ 1,\ldots, a_{p_{M+1}-1}\}$ or $\{a_{p_{N_0-M-1}+1},\ldots, a_N\}$, so in Mathematica speak it is sufficient to construct the lists

```
Take[lst {zlst[[k]]+1 ;; zlst[[k+maxZeros+2]]-1}]
```

for which `zlst[[k+maxZeros+2]]-zlst[[k]]-1 >= minLen` where `zlst` is the list of positions of the zeros in `lst` padded with `0` on the left and `Length[lst]+1` on the right. This could be implemented as

```
findLsts2[lst_, minLen_Integer?Positive, maxZeros_, 
  n : (_Integer | All) : All] :=
 Module[{zeroLst, rangeLst},
  zeroLst = Flatten[Position[lst, (0 | 0. | Null)]];
  If[Length[zeroLst] <= maxZeros,
   lst,
   rangeLst = Transpose[{Prepend[Drop[zeroLst + 1, -maxZeros], 1],
      Append[Drop[zeroLst - 1, maxZeros], Length[lst]]}];
   {Take[lst, #], #} & /@ 
    Select[rangeLst, (#[[2]] - #[[1]] + 1) >= minLen &, 
     n /. All -> Sequence[]]
   ]
  ]
```

This would return the sublists of maximum length which contain at most `maxZeros` zeros together with the indices of these sublists in the data list `lst`. Example

```
findLsts2[{1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0}, 4, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

This updated version of `findLsts2` randomly selects `n` sublists from all possible sublists of length `len` with at most `maxZeros` zeros from `lst`.

```
findLsts3[lst_, len_Integer?Positive, maxZeros_, 
  n : (_Integer | All) : All] :=
 Module[{zeroLst, rangeLst, startLst},
  zeroLst = Flatten[Position[lst, (0 | 0. | Null)]];
  If[Length[zeroLst] <= maxZeros,
   startLst = Range[Length[lst] - len + 1],
   rangeLst = Transpose[{Prepend[Drop[zeroLst + 1, -maxZeros], 1],
      Append[Drop[zeroLst - len, maxZeros], Length[lst] - len + 1]}];
   startLst = Flatten[Range @@@ (List @@ (Interval @@ 
          Select[rangeLst, (#[[2]] - #[[1]]) >= 0 &])), 1]];
  {lst[[# ;; # + len - 1]], #} & /@ Sort@RandomSample[startLst, n]
  ]
```

For the previous example we get

```
findLsts2[{1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0}, 4, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit 2**

The $k$-th pair in `rangelst` in `findLsts3` corresponds to the values $\{j_1, j_2\}$ such that 
$$p_{k-1}+1 = j_1
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
j_2+l-1 = p_{k+M+1}-1$$
where $l$ is the length of the sublist you want to extract and $p_k$ is as above. Provided that $j_{1}\leq j_{2}$ we then have that for all $j_{1}\leq j\leq j_{2}$ the sublist $\{a_j,\ldots,a_{j+l-1}\}$ is a subset of $\{ a_{p_{k-1}+1},\ldots, a_{p_{k+M+1}-1}\}$. What the `Select` statement in `startLst` does is to filter out the pairs in `rangelst` for which $j_1\leq j_2$ doesn't hold. `startLst` is then the `Union` of the ranges `Range[j1, j2]` for all remaining pairs.

Comment: thank you a lot for your answer. It's true I cannot use the previous answers as they only generate lists containing no zeros values.
But I still have a Issue here: I'm working with time series: Thus I need to have the list {0,2,0,3} {2,5} too, as it correspond to different time data points. I will try to look trough the code, any Idea how to adjust?
The Idea Behind: I will only need to Randomly pick 1 list of at least 250, but with a random date. Thus to not bias the statistics, I will need to have overlapping lists.

Comment: @PeriodicProgrammer Do you want to choose the lengths of the samples randomly as well, or are they fixed somehow (for example equal to the maximum length allowed)?

Comment: @ heike: the length is fixed to 251 data point, this corresponds to 1 event day + 250 workdays, thus 1 year.  
An adaption of your solution would be to generate sublist of every resultlist > 250 days, but because I'm working with a lot of data this might not be the fastest version.

Comment: The Result looks correct, the random selection considers all possible list? I will find it out but I have to retrace the code (which will take a moment :P).
Thank you a lot for your support!!

Comment: @PeriodicProgrammer Yes it does. the code works by generating a list of all possible first indices of the sublists (which is `startLst` in the code) and taking a random sample of those.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Could you give me a brief explanation of rangelst{{1,2},{3,3},{5,4},{7,10},{8,11}} and the (#[[2]] - #[[1]]) >= 0 &]? I'm stuck here at the momens :s.. thanks a lot!

Comment: additionally, it does not cover cases of a lot of zeros. so far: {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} returns too much lists with zero. probably one has to just remove all lists where Count[zeros]=length resultlist.
Edit: It Just occurs for len=maxZeros (and len<maxZero which goes against logic anyway).

Comment: @PeriodicProgrammer I've added an explanation of `rangelst` to my solution. What values did you take for `len` and `maxZeros` in the case for `{0,0,1,0,....0}`? If I try for example `findLsts3[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 4, 2]` I get an empty list which is what you would expect.

Comment: thank you for your explanation: I used the following values: `testsample = {0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.};`     `findLsts3[testsample, 4, 4]`

Answer (score 7):

Here is a rule-based version, which may be not the fastest but seems elegant (this is based on the same idea as the solution described in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/941/finding-a-subsequence-in-a-list/942#942)):

```
Clear[getSamples];
getSamples[data_List, minlen_Integer?Positive, n : (_Integer | All) : All] :=
   ReplaceList[
     data,
     {x___, p : Repeated[Except[0 | Null], {minlen, Infinity}], ___} :> {{p}, Length[{x}+1]},
     If[n === All, Sequence @@ {}, n]
   ]
```

It will return some number (ot all) of samples together with their starting positions. Here is a test sample (much smaller than what you need, just for an illustration):

```
testSample = RandomChoice[{0, Null}~Join~Range[5], 30]

(*
   ==>  {0, 3, 1, 0, 5, 5, 1, 2, Null, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 4, 1, 4, 3, 0, 0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 5,
           Null, 1, 4, Null, 2}
*)
```

Here are examples. First, find all samples with length at least 4:

```
getSamples[testSample, 4]

(*
   ==> {{{5, 5, 1, 2}, 5}, {{1, 2, 2, 1}, 10}, {{4, 1, 4, 3}, 15}}
*)
```

And now just the first of them (faster):

```
getSamples[testSample, 4, 1]

(*
   ==>  {{{5, 5, 1, 2}, 5}}
*)
```

This assumes that you have your data in the format of `testSample`.

An alternative way would be to use `Partition`, but it may be *memory* - inefficient for very large data (you create a list occupying about 250 times the memory of the original one, for your case). It can also be slower, if the needed sample can be found very early on, although typically will be faster. Still, here is the code:

```
Clear[getSamplesP];
getSamplesP[data_List, minlen_Integer?Positive, n : (_Integer | All) : All] := 
   Select[
     Transpose[{#, Range[Length[#]]}] &@ Partition[data, minlen, 1], 
     ! MemberQ[First@#, 0 | Null] &, 
     If[n =!= All, n, Sequence @@ {}]
]
```

you can use this in the same way.

Comment: oops, 14 min too late again...

Comment: A `_Integer?Positive` might be necessary here; unless you want to consider the generalization where the third argument could be a negative integer...

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, edited (although strict type-checking was not my primary intention here).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Length[{x}]+1` instead of `Length[{x}+1]` in the first version of `getSamples`? Also, the `Partition` version seems to be faster for larger lists than the first version.

Comment: @Heike I corrected already, thanks. As for large lists, you may be right, I just did not like the idea of such huge memory-inefficiency (like 250 times the memory for the original list). I will rephrase.

Comment: @J.M. Why don't you put this as an answer? I like it more than `Partition`, since it is more memory-efficient. You can also get positions,  by modifying your code a bit. It won't find as many as the `Partition`-based one though (because the latter will also find the overlapping ones), while `Partition`-based one won't find as many as the one based on `ReplaceList` (which will find them all - something probably not very useful).

Comment: @acl That was what I was thinking many times the last few days. Upon reflection, feels a bit sick though.

Comment: @Leonid Definitely not healthy

Answer (score 6):

At Leonid's prodding, and some mulling over on how to modify my original idea, I think this does what you want:

```
getSamples[data_List, minlen_Integer?Positive, n:(_Integer|All):All] :=
Module[{spl = SplitBy[data, MatchQ[#, 0|0.|Null] &]},
       Take[Select[Transpose[{spl, (Accumulate[#] - # + 1) &[Length /@ spl]}], 
                   (Length[First[#]] >= minlen) &], n]]
```

The `SplitBy[]` is key here; `data` is split according to whether it contains `0`, `0.` or `Null` (that is, with the pattern `0|0.|Null`), and the sublists of length `minlen` or longer are taken, I'll use Leonid's example here as well:

```
testSample = {0, 3, 1, 0, 5, 5, 1, 2, Null, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 4, 1, 4,
              3, 0, 0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 5, Null, 1, 4, Null, 2};

getSamples[testSample, 4]
{{{5, 5, 1, 2}, 5}, {{1, 2, 2, 1}, 10}, {{4, 1, 4, 3}, 15}}

getSamples[testSample, 4, -2]
{{{1, 2, 2, 1}, 10}, {{4, 1, 4, 3}, 15}}
```

Positive `n` does what you expect; negative values of `n`, as with *Mathematica* convention, take from the right.

---

If one wants to account for overlapping as well, some modification is necessary (borrowing slightly from Leonid):

```
getSamples[data_List, minlen_Integer?Positive, n:(_Integer|All):All] := 
 Module[{da = SplitBy[data, MatchQ[#, 0|0.|Null] &]},
  da = Function[l, 
     Transpose[
      Through[{Identity, Last[l] + Range[Length[#]] - 1 &}[
        Partition[First[l], minlen, 1]]]]] /@ 
    Select[Transpose[{da, (Accumulate[#] - # + 1) &[
        Length /@ da]}], (Length[First[#]] >= minlen) &];
  Take[Flatten[da, 1], n]]
```

As an example:

```
getSamples[testSample, 3]
{{{5, 5, 1}, 5}, {{5, 1, 2}, 6}, {{1, 2, 2}, 10}, {{2, 2, 1}, 11},
 {{4, 1, 4}, 15}, {{1, 4, 3}, 16}, {{4, 1, 4}, 21}}
```

Comment: +1 - this is a good and efficient alternative.

Comment: thank you both a lot for the answer, as I'm not a very advanced user yet, I will take my time and start to understand the code fully, I'll give feedback when i sucessfully (or not) implemented it ;)

Comment: unfortunately its true that this only gives me list with no zeros. But i have a limit of 10 zeroes because 1 missing element would make a lot of experiments useless, even though they are of good quality, see Heike's ansatz..

Comment: @Per: Could you please come up with a minimal example and show what output you're expecting from the function(s) you want to see from us?

Comment: @J.M.  getSamples[data, fixlen, maxzero, n]; getsamples[testsample, 4,1]: Leads to:
{3, 1, 0, 5}
{1, 0, 5, 5}
{0, 5, 5, 1}
{5, 5, 1, 2}
…
{4, 1, 4, 3}
{1, 4, 3, 0}
{0, 4, 1, 4}
This is needed because: I need to (mostly) unbiased draw a random set of 1 year data (thus I will afterwards randomly select 1 valid list, if the experiment contains one). Dublicates needed as every resulting list is subject to another time frame.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution uses `Partition` and `Count`:

```
$data = {1,0,2,0,3,0,Null,0,2,4,5,6,7,0};
$runLength = 4;
$tolerance = 2;

Cases[Partition[$data, $runLength, 1], l_ /; Count[l, 0|Null] <= $tolerance]
```

> {{1,0,2,0},{0,2,0,3},{2,0,3,0},{Null,0,2,4},{0,2,4,5},{2,4,5,6},{4,5,6,7},{5,6,7,0}}

Unfortunately, this solution does not scale well.  It uses a lot of memory by creating and scanning a list containing every run.  For large input lists, this is not feasible.  Furthermore, it performs a number of operations proportional to the product of the input and run lengths.  The following function performs better, using far less memory and with performance linearly proportional to the input size:

```
goodRunPositions[data_, runLength_, tolerance_] :=
  data /. Null -> 0 //
  Sign //
  Abs //
  1 - # & //
  Accumulate //
  Prepend[#, 0] &//
  #[[runLength+1;;]] - #[[;;-runLength-1]] &//
  Position[#, n_ /; n <= tolerance] &//
  Flatten

goodRunPositions[$data, $runLength, $tolerance]
```

> {1,2,3,7,8,9,10,11}

A helper function can be used to extract a run at any given position:

```
extractRun[data_, runLength_, position_] :=
  data[[position ;; position+runLength-1]]

extractRun[$data, $runLength, 7]
```

> {Null,0,2,4}

... or to randomly select a run ...

```
randomGoodRun[data_, runLength_, tolerance_] :=
  extractRun[
    $data
  , $runLength
  , RandomChoice @ goodRunPositions[data, runLength, tolerance]
  ]

randomGoodRun[$data, $runLength, $tolerance]
```

> {2,4,5,6}

Performance is adequate for larger lists:

```
randomData[w_, n_] :=
  RandomChoice[{w, w, 100, 100, 100, 100} -> {Null, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, n]

SeedRandom[923874]
$10K = randomData[20, 10000];
$1M = randomData[25, 1000000];
$10M = randomData[30, 10000000];

goodRunPositions[$10K, 250, 10] // Timing // Column
```

> 0.016 {7425,7426,7427,7428,7429,7430,7431,7432,7433,7434,7435,7436,7437,7438,7439,7440,7441,7442,7443,7446,7447,7448,7449,7450,7451,7452,7453,7454,7455,7456,7457,7458,7459,7460,7461,7462,7463,7464,7465,7466,7467,7468,7469,7470,7471,7472,7473,7474,7475,7476,7477,7478,7479,7480,7481,7482,7483,7484,7485,7486,7487,7488,7489,7490,7491,7492,7493,7494,7495,7496,7497,7498}

```
goodRunPositions[$1M, 250, 10] // Timing // Column
```

> 0.811 {5879,5880,5881,5882,5883,5884,5885,5886,5887,5888,5889,5890,5891,5892,5893,5894,5895,5896,5897,5898,5899,5900,5901,5902,5903,5904,5905,5906,5907,5908,5909,5910,5911,5912,896682,896683,896684}

```
goodRunPositions[$10M, 250, 10] // Timing // Column
```

> 8.221 {3399940,3399941,3399942,3399943,3399944,3399945,3399946,3399947,3399948,3399949,3399950,3399951,3399952,3399953,3399954,3399955,3399956,3399957,3399958,3399959,3399960,3399961,3399962,3399963,3399964,3399965,3399966,3399967,3399968,7027173}

**How Does It Work?**

Here is our toy data set:

```
$data
```

> {1,0,2,0,3,0,Null,0,2,4,5,6,7,0}

The first step is to identify nulls and zeros.  In order to allow us to use the fast built-in tensor operations, we change nulls to zeroes first:

```
$data /. Null -> 0 // Sign // Abs // 1 - # &
```

> {0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1}

Every null or zero value has been assigned a score of one and other values are scored zero.  We can now generate a running total of the number of zero values encountered:

```
% // Accumulate
```

> {0,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6}

To determine the number of zeroes in any given run, we can simply take the difference between the number of zeroes at the beginning and the end of the run.  We'll need to prepend a zero to the list to handle the first run:

```
Prepend[%, 0] //
#[[$runLength+1;;]] - #[[;;-$runLength-1]] &
```

> {2,2,2,3,3,3,2,1,0,0,1}

Now it is just a simple matter of finding the positions of the elements where the zero count remains below the threshold:

```
Position[%, n_ /; n <= $tolerance] // Flatten
```

> {1,2,3,7,8,9,10,11}

We can use `extractRun` inspect the runs themselves:

```
extractRun[$data, $runLength, #] & /@ % // Column
```

> {1,0,2,0}
>   {0,2,0,3}
>   {2,0,3,0}
>   {Null,0,2,4}
>   {0,2,4,5}
>   {2,4,5,6}
>   {4,5,6,7}
>   {5,6,7,0}

Comment: Sorry for the cursing at the end of the response `#]&/@%//` :)

Comment: thank you for the alternative solution!