# Match a sequence of integers

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, sequence

I would to match a pattern

```
 p1 = 0,0,1,0,0
```

to the elements in listA. The elements are a boolean sequence that may look like this

```
 {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Every where p1 matches the sequence I want to change that part into

```
 p2 = .5, .5, 1, .5, .5
```

that will change listA into

```
 {{.5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1, 0, 1, 1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5},   {0, 0, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 0, 0}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What with overlapping, `{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0}`?

Comment: Note that you cannot assign a raw sequence such as `p1 = 0,0,1,0,0`.  You can use `Sequence` e.g. `p1 = Sequence[0,0,1,0,0]` but most of the time it is easier to just work with lists as shown in my answer.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard. Thank You! I have been studying the code and I have two questions. Why is the first argument `{s}` passed in wrapped in a `List`? Also do I have this right, The function will only execute with condition `Length[List[s]] == Length[r]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your basic (simple, but inefficient) method is to use [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html):

```
start =
 {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

start //. {a___, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, b___} :> {a, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, b}
```

> ```
> {{0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5},
>  {0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0}}
> ```

Your next level of optimization is to find all the positions first, and then replace.
  I'll use a nice [`ReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceList.html) method from [Jan Pöschko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8740525/618728) for the sequence position step.

```
f[{s__}, r_List][v_List] /; Length[{s}] == Length[r] :=
 Module[{m = v, n = Length[{s}]},
  m[[# + 1 ;; # + n]] = r; & /@
   ReplaceList[v, {a___, s, ___} :> Length[{a}]];
  m
 ]

p1 = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
p2 = {.5, .5, 1, .5, .5};

f[p1, p2] /@ start
```

> ```
> {{0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5},
>  {0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0}}
> ```

For ultimate optimization you would use a faster sequence position function such as `seqposCB` from Leonid Shifrin posted in [position of sequence of elements in list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/position-of-sequence-of-elements-in-list/8926#8926).

---

For a literal pattern as in this example the function [`SequencePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html) introduced in 10.1.0 provides a much faster method than `ReplaceList` shown above.

```
f2[s_List, r_List][v_List] /; Length[s] == Length[r] :=
 Module[
  {m = v, n = Length[s]}, m[[# ;; #2]] = r; & @@@ SequencePosition[v, s];
  m
 ]

rand = RandomInteger[1, 50000];
AbsoluteTiming[r1 = f[p1, p2][rand];]  // First
AbsoluteTiming[r2 = f2[p1, p2][rand];] // First
r1 === r2
```

> ```
> 0.551052
>
> 0.00407597
>
> True
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sequenceReplace` defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100903/2266), you can do It as:

```
list = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
sequenceReplace[#, {0,0,1,0,0}:> Sequence@@{.5, .5, 1, .5, .5}]&/@list
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have `SequencePosition`:

```
ReplaceSequence[list_, fr_, to_] :=
 With[{le = Length@fr},
  ReplacePart[
   list,
   Dispatch[
    Rule @@@ 
     Level[
       Map[Transpose[{#, to}] &, 
         Map[Range[#, # + le - 1] &, 
           Flatten@Position[Partition[list, le, 1], f]]],
     {2}]
    ]]]

ReplaceSequence[RandomInteger[1, 50000], fr, to]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First

0.070000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list =
  {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

p1 = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
p2 = {.5, .5, 1, .5, .5};
```

Since V 11.3 there is `SequenceReplace` and since V 12.1 `Splice`

```
SequenceReplace[#, p1 :> Splice @ p2] & /@ list
```

gives the expected result:

```
{{0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5}, 
{0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0}}
```