# Extracting sequences delimited by two String markers from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

Suppose I have a list of arbitrary length:

```
{1, 2, 3, "Open", 3, 2, "Close", 9, 3, 4, "Open", 1, 0, "Close", 3, 5}
```

and I am trying to extract the sequences delimited by the "Open"/"Close" tags, i.e. the answer I want is:

```
{{3, 2}, {1, 0}}
```

What's the right way to do this? The data I am actually working with is a large XML document and I am trying to extract sections of it by identifying certain tags as boundaries. I've fiddled with different pattern matching functions but can't figure out how to operate on a list in this way since I am trying to match patterns on an intermediate level between individual elements and the entire list.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I don't know in advance how many such sequences the data will contain or how many elements will be present between any particular set of tags.

Comment: ugly: `Take[list, #] & /@ (Partition[
    Flatten[Position[list, "Open" | "Close"]], 
    2] /. {a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ} -> {a + 1, b - 1})`

Comment: Closely related: [(941)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/941/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one

```
ReplaceList[expr, {__, PatternSequence["Open",v__ /; Count[{v}, _String] == 0, 
            _String], __} -> {v}]
```

Comment: If you don't `Flatten` the data from the xml `Case` will be a good alternative.

Comment: Good call on `ReplaceList`

Comment: Maybe change `PatternSequence["Open", 
 v__ /; Count[{v}, _?(# == "Close" &)] == 0, "Close"]` in case the list contains other strings than `"Open"|"Close"`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks yes the correct structure of the pattern will depend on the actual data, if the tags contain also in the data strings the OP should exclude just the xml tags. My opinion is that the `XMLObject` and `XMLElement` objects must be exploited instead of a flattened list.

Comment: I would use the pattern `{__, PatternSequence["Open", v : Except["Close"] .., "Close"], __}` from the answer below. That should be more efficient that using a test function.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a plain pattern approach, I'm not quite sure how robust it is:

```
ReplaceList[expr, {___, "Open", x : Except["Close"] ..., "Close", ___} :> {x}]
```

Also take a look at `Longest` and `Shortest`, which may come in handy.

Answer (score 5):

In versions 10.1+, you  can use `SequenceCases`:

```
 lst={1, 2, 3, "Open", 3, 2, "Close", 9, 3, 4, "Open", 1, 0, "Close", 3, 5};
 SequenceCases[lst, {"Open", x:Except["Close"].., "Close"} :> {x}]
```

> {{3, 2}, {1, 0}}

Comment: How could one use the `Shortest` construct here for `x`?

Comment: `SequenceCases[lst, {"Open", Shortest[x__Integer], "Close"} :> {x}]` works, but,for some reason, `SequenceCases[lst, {"Open", Shortest[x__], "Close"} :> {x}]` does not.

Answer (score 3):

```
Split[lst, (#1 =!= "Close" && #2 =!= "Open") &] // 
 Cases[{"Open", x__, "Close"} :> {x}]
```

> {{3, 2}, {1, 0}}

Comment: (+1) This is faster!

Answer (score 2):

My humble attempt:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, "Open", 3, 2, "Close", 9, 3, 4, "Open", 1, 0, 
   "Close", 3, 5};
SplitBy[
 Select[list, 
  (open = # != "Close" && (# == "Open" || open)) &], # == "Open" &] 
    //. "Open" | {} -> Sequence[]
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel this is way too complicated, but anyway:

```
l = {1, 2, 3, "Open", 3, 4, 5, 2, "Close", 9, 3, 4, "Open", 0, 
   "Close", "Close", 3, 5};

Reap[l //. {a___, 
     PatternSequence["Open", mid : _?NumericQ .., "Close"], 
     b___} :> {a, Sow[{mid}]; mid, b}][[2, 1]]
```

> {{3, 4, 5, 2}, {0}}

This example might have some limited instructional value showing one convoluted possible use of `Sow` and `Reap`.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, "Open", x__ /; FreeQ[{x}, "Close"], "Close", ___} -> {x}]
```

(although amr's one seems better)

Answer (score 1):

```
positions = (data // {PositionIndex[#]["Open"],PositionIndex[#]["Close"]} & 
// Transpose )
```

> {{4, 7}, {11, 14}}

```
data[[Span[# + {1, -1}]]] & /@ positions
```

> {{3, 2}, {1, 0}}

Answer (score 1):

Splitting twice:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, "Open", 3, 2, "Close", 9, 3, 4, "Open", 1, 0, "Close", 3, 5};

Join @@ Cases[{{_?NumberQ, ___}}] @
  Split[SplitBy[list, NumberQ], #1 != {"Open"} && #2 != {"Close"} &]
```

{{3, 2}, {1, 0}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Subsequences` and `Cases`:

```
Subsequences[lst] // Cases[{"Open", x__?NumberQ, "Close"} :> {x}]

(*{{3, 2}, {1, 0}}*)
```

Comment: In general, this is feasible as long as the size of the list remains in check.