# How to replace an element in a list based on the value of the next element?

Tags: list-manipulation

I use *Mathematica* a little bit. I try to understand it, but it is hard

I have a list of 5 numbers selected randomly from 0 and -1. I have to replace a 0 with a 1 when the 0 is followed by -1.

My wrong solution is:

```
list = RandomInteger[{-1, 0}, 5] 
(* {0, 0, 0, -1, 0} *)

list /. x_ /; x == 0 -> 1
(* {1, 1, 1, -1, 1} *)
```

I need get: `{0, 0, 1, -1, 0}`. How do I manipulate a list to change the previous element if the next element is -1?

Comment: Related: [Finding a subsequence in a list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/941/finding-a-subsequence-in-a-list)

Answer (score 18):

One of the possible solutions:

```
list = RandomInteger[{-1, 0}, 5]
(* {0, -1, 0, 0, -1} *)

list2 = list + Append[UnitStep[-1 - Differences[list]], 0]
(* {1, -1, 0, 1, -1} *)
```

Another two are

```
Partition[list, 2, 1, 1, 0] /. {{0, -1} -> 1, {n_, _} :> n}
(* {1, -1, 0, 1, -1} *)

f[_, n_] := n;
f[-1, 0] := 1;
Reverse@FoldList[f, list[[-1]], Rest@Reverse@list]
(* {1, -1, 0, 1, -1} *)
```

The first solution is very fast for big lists. It takes $0.08$ s for a list with $1\,000\,000$ elements. The second and the third one take $0.8$ s. Halirutan's `ReplaceAll` will take several hours because it has $O(n^2)$ complexity.

**Update**

One can use [cellular automata](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CellularAutomata.html):

```
CellularAutomaton[{{_, 0, -1} -> 1, {_, n_, _} :> n}, list, 1][[2]]
(* {1, -1, 0, 1, -1} *)

f[{n_, _}] := n;
f[{0, -1}] := 1;
CellularAutomaton[{f[#]&, {}, {{0}, {1}}}, list, 1][[2]]
(* {1, -1, 0, 1, -1} *)
```

It is not very fast ($1.8$ s for $1\,000\,000$ elements) but it shows wide opportunities of *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 15):

One pattern solution is simply

```
list //. {s___, 0, -1, e___} :> {s, 1, -1, e}
```

Answer (score 13):

This should be pretty fast:

```
list - (list + 1) Join[Rest[list], {0}]
```

Comment: +1, neat one, Append is faster though

Comment: @Coolwater, `Join` is a tiny bit faster for me.

Comment: +1, a bit faster then my `UnitStep`.

Answer (score 11):

Since no one has suggested it, there is also `` Developer`PartitionMap `` which maps a function across a partitioned list:

```
list = RandomInteger[{-1, 0}, 5]
Clear[f];
f[{0, -1}] := 1
f[{x_, _}] := x
Developer`PartitionMap[f, list, 2, 1, 1, 0]
(* {0, 0, -1, 0, -1} *)
(* {0, 1, -1, 1, -1} *)
```

Comment: Not as fast as the pure numeric methods but far more general. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I like ``Developer`PartitionMap`` because of its relative compactness and simplicity. While not a speed demon, I think the other factors make it a nice contender.

Comment: [I like it too.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A121+PartitionMap)

Answer (score 6):

I implemented a solution based on linked lists, discussed by Leonid Shifrin [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/731).

```
toLinkedList[l_List] := Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Reverse@l]
replRec[l_List] := replRec[toLinkedList[l], {}]
replRec[{0, tail : {-1, _List}}, res_] := replRec[tail, {1, res}]
replRec[{int_Integer, tail_List}, res_] := replRec[tail, {int, res}]
replRec[{}, res_] := Reverse[Flatten[res]]
```

For example

```
replRec[{0, 0, 0, -1, 0}]
(* Out: {0, 0, 1, -1, 0} *)
```

I tried this on a list of the size of 10^6, which required me to change the iteration limit:

```
Block[{$IterationLimit = 10^7}, replRec[list]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

It took 1.34 seconds, compared to 0.39 with Michael E2's Replace method.

Comment: +1. It crossed my mind to try it here, but I didn't have the time.

Answer (score 5):

Not so fast but faster than replacement rules and fun. We are going to scan on reversed list and each `-1` or `0` will change the value of `Sown` element.

```
list = RandomInteger[{-1, 0}, 10]
```

> ```
> {-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0}
> ```

```
f[0] := (Sow[g[0]]; g[0] = 0;);
f[-1] := ((g[0] = 1); Sow[-1])

g[0] = Sow[0]; (*default value*)

Reap[Scan[f, Reverse@list]][[2, 1]] // Reverse
```

> ```
> {-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

This is just another approach:

```
f[0] = 1; f[-1] = -1;
MapAt[f, list, Position[Rest[list], -1, {1}]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `SequenceReplace`

```
list = {0, 0, 0, -1, 0};

SequenceReplace[list, {0, -1} :> Splice @ {1, -1}]
```

{0, 0, 1, -1, 0}

```
list = {0, -1, 0, 0, -1};

SequenceReplace[list, {0, -1} :> Splice @ {1, -1}]
```

{1, -1, 0, 1, -1}

Somehow nicer (thanks bmf):

```
SequenceReplace[list, {0, -1} :> Sequence[1, -1]]
```

- `SequenceReplace` since V 11.3
- `Splice` since V 12.1

Comment: (+1) and very nicely done. Perhaps you could, also, include `SequenceReplace[list, {0, -1} :> Sequence[1, -1]]` as a small variant

Answer (score 4):

a basic solution :

```
    list = RandomInteger[{-1, 0}, 5]
    (* {0, -1, 0, 0, -1} *)  

    Append[
         Table[If[list[[i + 1]] === -1, 1, list[[i]]], {i, Length[list] - 1}],
         Last[list]]
```

> {1, -1, 0, 1, -1}

It is fast.

Answer (score 4):

A general way with patterns, that is pretty efficient and of linear complexity.  (@halirutan's is also easily adapted to general patterns).  Here `pat` should be of the form `{pat1, lookahead} -> replacement`):

```
seqRep[list_, pat_] :=
  (Replace[Partition[list, 2, 1], {pat, {x_, y_} :> x}, {1}]) ~Append~ Last[list]
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomInteger[{-1, 0}, 10]
(* {0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0} *)

seqRep[list, {0, -1} -> 1]
(* {0, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0} *)
```

A fast way, that like others works on the OP's example of a list of integers. Its speed comes from auto-parallelization:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Integer}, {y, _Integer}},
  If[x == 0 && y == -1, 1, x],
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]
```

Usage:

```
cf[Most@list, Rest@list]~Append~Last[list]
(* {0, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0} *)
```

As far as speed, on a list of `10^6` integers, the `Replace` method took 0.42 sec., the compiled method took 0.051 sec., @ybeltukov's  `UnitStep` method took 0.071 sec., and Simon Wood's method took 0.071 sec.

Answer (score 2):

We can, also, use [**`SequencePosition`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html)+[**`ReplaceAt`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAt.html)

```
list1 = {0, 0, 0, -1, 0};
list2 = {0, -1, 0, 0, -1};
ReplaceAt[list1, 0 -> 1, 
 List /@ SequencePosition[list1, {0, -1}][[All, 1]]]
ReplaceAt[list2, 0 -> 1, 
 List /@ SequencePosition[list2, {0, -1}][[All, 1]]]
```

with the results being

> `{0, 0, 1, -1, 0}`
>
> `{1, -1, 0, 1, -1}`

Answer (score 2):

Using `ReplacePart` and `Position`:

```
list1 = {0, 0, 0, -1, 0};

pos[l_List] := Select[(x |-> x - 1)@Position[#, -1] &@l, Extract[l, #] == 0 &]

ReplacePart[#, pos[#] -> 1] &@list1

(*{0, 0, 1, -1, 0}*)

list2 = {0, -1, 0, 0, -1};

ReplacePart[#, pos[#] -> 1] &@list2

(*{1, -1, 0, 1, -1}*)

list3 = {0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0};

ReplacePart[#, pos[#] -> 1] &@list3

(*{0, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0}*)
```

A procedural way using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
With[{lst = list3},
   Reap[
     Do[
      If[
       i < Length[lst] && lst[[i]] == 0 && lst[[i + 1]] == -1, 
           Sow[1], Sow[lst[[i]]]
       ], {i, Length[lst]}
      ]
     ][[2, 1]]
  ]

(*{0, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0}*)
```