# Compare 2 lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to compare 2 lists. One is very large and I need to compare many times.

Lets say `Length[list1] < Length[list2]`.

I need to know how many times `list1` occures in `list2`.

```
list1 = {1, 0}
list2 = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}
```

So the result would be 2 (at position 1 and 3).

Furthermore list1 can countain wildcards

```
list1 = {1, 2}
```

Where 2 is a wildcard, so with `list2` from above the result would be 3 (at position 1,3,5).

I solved this with a few `For` loops. It works but is really slow. I need to speed it up very much.

What I got:

With `list1` as `lMask` and `list2` as `BitData`

```
GetFits[i_] := Block[{icount, lMask},
  icount = 0;
  lMask = IntegerDigits[i, 3];
  If[lMask[[-1]] != 2 ,
   If[ lMask[[1]] != 2,
    For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[BitData] + 1 - Length[lMask], ii++,
     If[FitAt[lMask, ii] == 1, icount++;];
     ];
    icount
    , -1]
   , -1]
  ]


FitAt[lMask_, iPos_] := (For[i = 1, i <= Length[lMask], i++,
   If[lMask[[i]] != 2,
     If[lMask[[i]] != BitData[[i + iPos - 1]],
       Return[0]
       ];
     ];
   ];
  1)
```

Comment: The answer has been described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364804/a-fast-implementation-in-mathematica-for-position2d/) (functions `seqPos` and `seqPosC` in my answer there), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740033/is-there-an-equivalent-of-stringposition-for-searching-lists-if-not-whats-t).

Comment: Closely related: [(941)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/941/121)

Answer (score 7):

```
list2 = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1};
list1 = {1, 0};

p2 = Partition[list2, Length[list1], 1];
Count[p2, list1]
Flatten@Position[p2, list1]
```

> 2
>
> {1, 3}

Now with 2 as a wildcard.

```
list1 = {1, 2};
list1 = list1 /. {2 -> _};
```

and same again

```
p2 = Partition[list2, Length[list1], 1];
Count[p2, list1]
Flatten@Position[p2, list1]
```

> 3
>
> {1, 3, 5}

Answer (score 6):

I assume your *Lists* are of numbers.  You can convert them to *Strings* and use *StringCount* or *StringCases*:

```
MyList1 = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
MyTest = {1, 0};

StringCount[StringJoin[ToString /@ MyList1], 
StringJoin[ToString /@ MyTest]]

Length[StringCases[StringJoin[ToString /@ MyList1], 
StringJoin[ToString /@ MyTest]]]
```

This has the added benefit that you can choose to allow or disallow overlapping cases, with `Overlaps -> True` or `Overlaps -> False` within `StringCount`.

Answer (score 4):

In versions 10+, there is [SequenceCount](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCount.html?q=SequenceCount) that does exactly what is needed:

> ***SequenceCount[list,sub]**
>   gives a count of the number of times **sub** appears as a sublist of **list**.*

```
list1 = {1, 0};
list2 = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1};

SequenceCount[list2, list1]
```

> 2

It also works  with patterns,

```
SequenceCount[list2, {1, _}]
```

> 3

Note: The last one could be very slow. See:[Performance problems in new Sequence functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83325/121).

Comment: Beware that using patterns in `SequenceCount` is *very slow*; see [(83325)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83325/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, i added a note with the link.

Answer (score 3):

If your lists are actually binary then pre-partitioning can be done in an efficient way:

```
 biglist = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 2000];
 Clear[partition];
 partition[len_] := 
       partition[len]  = 
         FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ Partition[biglist , len , 1  ];
 findsub[small_List  ] := 
      Flatten@Position[ partition[Length[small]]   ,  
         FromDigits[small, 2] , 1, Heads -> False]

 findsub[{1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}]
```

> {146, 677, 699, 1220, 1238, 1286, 1663, 1717}

```
 biglist[[146 ;; 146 + 7]]
```

> {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}

wildcard version:

```
 findsub[small_List ] := Module[{
   s = Flatten@Position[ small , Except[2] , {1}, Heads -> False ] },
   Flatten@Position[ partition[Length[small]]   ,  x_ /;
       IntegerDigits[x, 2, Length[small]][[s]] == small[[s]]  , 1, 
           Heads -> False] ]
```

Comment: If the lists are not binary, one can interpret the parts (of length Length@smallist) as numbers with an appropriate base. Then this should work also.

Answer (score 2):

Not the best method, but an option to explore the [Slot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) function

```
list1={1,0};list2={1,0,1,0,1,1};
Flatten[Position[({list2[[#1]],list2[[#1+1]]}&)/@Range[Length[list2]-1],list1]]
Length[%]
```

> {1,3}
>
> 2

```
list1={1,2};list1=list1/.{2->_};list2={1,0,1,0,1,1};
Flatten[Position[({list2[[#1]],list2[[#1+1]]}&)/@Range[Length[list2]-1],list1]]
Length[%]
```

> {1,3,5}
>
> 3