# Performance problems in new Sequence functions

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, sequence, language-design

The new-in-10.1 [`Sequence*` family](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn101.html) of functions should provide newly optimized methods for handling sequence problems.  Happily in some cases they do!  For example [Murta reports 28 times faster performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78757/121) from [`SequencePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html) than a [`ReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html) alternative.

However there also seem to be major problems in other cases.

### `Alternatives`

When looking for multiple subsequences using [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) performance degrades.

Let's try counting the appearances of several short sequences within an integer list.  Here are three functions to do the same operation, one based on [`StringCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCount.html), one on `ReplaceList`, and one on the new [`SequenceCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCount.html).

```
pat = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 0}};

ts = ToString @ Row[#, ","] &;

f1 = StringCount[ts@#, ts /@ pat, Overlaps -> True] &;
f2 = Length @ ReplaceList[#, ({___, ##, ___} -> 1) & @@@ pat] &;
f3 = SequenceCount[#, Alternatives @@ pat, Overlaps -> True] &;
```

We can see that their results agree:

```
foo = RandomInteger[3, 500];
#[foo] & /@ {f1, f2, f3}
```

> ```
> {57, 57, 57}
> ```

The string method has the overhead of converting the list and sublists strings, and `ReplaceList` first builds a list of results before counting them with `Length`.  Surely `SequenceCount` should be fastest being written for this exact operation and without superfluous overhead.  However that is far from the case.

(First you will need to patch the [broken-in-10.1.0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83226/121) `BenchmarkPlot` if you intend to follow along.)

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3}, RandomInteger[3, #] &, TimeConstraint -> 15]
```

[image]

This is catastrophically poor performance from `SequenceCount`!  (Note the log-log scale.)
Its complexity is through the roof at apparently $O(n^3)$.

Let us introduce a fourth function also using `SequenceCount` but eliminating `Alternatives`:

```
f4 = Sum[SequenceCount[#, ss, Overlaps -> True], {ss, pat}] &;
```

Note that this will scan the list once for each list in `pat` so theoretically it should be proportionately slower, however:

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3, f4}, RandomInteger[3, #] &, TimeConstraint -> 15]
```

[image]

This gives us $O(n)$ complexity with a lower coefficient than `f1`!

`SequenceCases` and `SequencePosition` exhibit similar behavior regarding `Alternatives`.

What is causing this and is there another solution besides scanning the list separately for each subsequence?

### Plain patterns

Unlike the literal sequences in the first section the introduction of patterns adds potential complication for matching.  For example pattern tests could potentially have side effects. (See: [PatternTest not optimized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8484299/618728))

However plain patterns should be handled efficiently.  As evidence we can again compare string performance to that of the new `Sequence*` functions.  First with a fixed-length pattern:

```
BenchmarkPlot[
 {StringPosition[ToString@Row@#, "11" ~~ _ ~~ "0" ~~ _] &,
  SequencePosition[#, {1, 1, _, 0, _}] &},
 RandomInteger[3, #] &
]
```

[image]

And now with a variable-length pattern:

```
BenchmarkPlot[
 {StringPosition[ToString@Row@#, "11" ~~ __ ~~ "0"] &,
  SequencePosition[#, {1, 1, __, 0}] &},
 RandomInteger[3, #] &
]
```

[image]

Pretty much catastrophic again.  Unlike the `Alternatives` issue there doesn't appear to be a work-around so despite the new functions I expect that when working with patterns I will still be recasting problems in terms of String functions which frankly is a shame.

Is there any justification for the poor performance I am witnessing or is this yet another function that was pushed out the door too soon?

Comment: Disappointment strikes again...

Comment: The `Sequence*` functions are implemented in top level, so they were never going to be much faster than using other functions. However, they should not be an order of magnitude slower. I've filed a report internally to get this looked at.

Comment: Update : Improvements have been made to the `Sequence*` functions in our latest development builds that address all of these except the variable-length pattern case, which is trickier to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Stefan -- can you tell me if these are going to be recoded as low-level functions for performance?

Comment: It will still be in top level. In the latest builds, the performance of `f3` is now equal to `f4` in your `Alternatives` example, and for plain patterns (your second example) `SequenceCases` will have the same complexity but lower coefficient than `StringPosition` (and hence faster for `n` greater than about 100 in my testing).

Comment: On version 10.3: [Alternatives](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ciBQc.png), [Plain patterns fixed-length](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nadvr.png), and [Plain patterns variable-length](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1hLuh.png).

Comment: @Karsten7. Thanks!

Comment: No performance changes in version 11.0 compared to 10.3.

Comment: Not sure how many are interested, but these are the results of `BenchmarkPlot` in [**`12.0.0`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmzyo.png) and [**`13.2.0`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLkdV.png)