# Using Rules inside SequenceCases degrades Performance

Tags: functions, system-performance

Consider the following:

```
SequenceCases[Range[10^4], {a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0058148, Null}

If we now try to use a rule to transform the matched cases, performance degrades considerably (about 2 orders of magnitude):

```
SequenceCases[Range[10^4], {a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ} :> {a, c}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.635604, Null}

One can simply apply `ReplaceAll` afterwards and get much better performance:

```
SequenceCases[Range[10^4], {a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ}] /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, c};
              // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.00655593, Null}

Why does a simple rule application cause `SequenceCases` to slow down considerably?

Comment: I was going to say unpacking, but like `Cases` it appears as if `SequenceCases` always unpacks.

Comment: Closely related: [(83325)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83325/121)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's start by looking at the code for `SequenceCases`:

```
<< GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitions[SequenceCases]
```

We can see in this code that three different conditions determine whether the expression will be evaluated by `sequenceCasesSublist` or `sequenceCasesPattern`. Let's evaluate the two tests that matter on `{a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ}` and `{a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ} :> {a, c}` respectively.

```
{
 SymbolicTensors`UtilitiesDump`VariableLengthPatternFreeQ[{a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ}],
 SymbolicTensors`UtilitiesDump`VariableLengthPatternFreeQ[{a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ} :> {a, c}]
}
```

> `{True, True}`

```
{
 SymbolicTensors`UtilitiesDump`ListRepresentationQ[{a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ} :> {a, c}], 
 SymbolicTensors`UtilitiesDump`ListRepresentationQ[{a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ}]
}
```

> `{False, True}`

Because they do not return the same result on this last test, they are actually handled by different functions, and it seems like `sequenceCasesSublist` is much faster than `sequenceCasesPattern`.

If we run

```
PrintDefinitions[SymbolicTensors`UtilitiesDump`sequenceCasesPattern]
```

we can see that the very first thing that `sequenceCasesPattern` does is to rewrite the expression in this form:

```
Replace[SequenceCases[Range[10^4], {a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ}], {a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ} :> {a, c}, 1]
```

which is fast like your `ReplaceAll` version, because it can be evaluated with `sequenceCasesSublist`. However, in the source code, instead of `SequenceCases` the function `sequenceCasesPattern` is used, which never runs the initial tests of `SequenceCases`; therefore it doesn't realize that it can choose the fast routine. That's why it's slow.

`sequenceCasesPattern`, I may add, is implemented with `ReplaceList`.

Comment: Nice diagnosis! We're looking into it!

Answer (score 2):

With *Mathematica* version 11.1.0 there is no slowdown anymore:

```
$Version
SequenceCases[Range[10^6], {a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ}]; // AbsoluteTiming
SequenceCases[Range[10^6], {a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ} :> {a, c}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> "11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)"
>
> {1.13733, Null}
>
> {1.13629, Null}
> ```

Here is output from version 11.0.1:

```
$Version
SequenceCases[Range[10^4], {a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ}]; // AbsoluteTiming
SequenceCases[Range[10^4], {a_?PrimeQ, b_, c_?PrimeQ} :> {a, c}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> "11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)"
>
> {0.016909744048664993`, Null}
>
> {1.1500872252585508`, Null}
> ```

So the problem was fixed in version 11.1.0.