# Slow performance of SequenceCases

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, pattern-matching

While working on a [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278064/how-to-plot-root-curves-from-topological-changing-curves/278658#278658) to another question, I noticed some <s>performance regression</s> slow performance of SequenceCases and friends. Consider a problem of finding zeroes of a function, given a sorted table of its values:

```
$Version (* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

zeros[lst_] := SequenceCases[lst, {a_, b_} /; Sign[a[[2]]] != Sign[b[[2]]]]
```

For simplicity, instead of finding zeros, we find intervals containing them.

```
zeros[Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 5, 0.1}]] 
(* {{{0., 0.}, {0.1, 0.0998334}}, {{3.1, 0.0415807}, {3.2, -0.0583741}}} *)
```

Using SequenceCases with pattern matching results in a very compact code. Unfortunately, this code has some terrible performance characteristics: e.g., asking SequenceCases to process a list of 1000 elements takes considerable time:

```
zeros[Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 100, 0.1}]] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.68121, 32} *)

zeros[Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 200, 0.1}]] // Length // AbsoluteTiming 
(* {12.2768, 64} *)
```

Notice that non-linear growth in the execution time: it increases by 7.3x while the input double in size.

Now compare this to a straightforward alternative using a loop, which is almost instantaneous:

```
fastZeros[lst_] := 
 First[Reap[
    Do[If[Sign[lst[[i, 2]]] != Sign[lst[[i + 1, 2]]], 
      Sow[{lst[[i]], lst[[i + 1]]}]], {i, Length[lst] - 1}]][[2]], {}]

With[{data = Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 5, 0.1}]}, 
 fastZeros[data] == zeros[data]] (* True *)

fastZeros[Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 200, 0.1}]] // Length // AbsoluteTiming 
(* {0.003667, 64} *)
```

While I expect to have some speed tradeoff when using more powerful language constructs like pattern matching, it still seems like a severe performance penalty. Similar things were [discussed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89874/using-rules-inside-sequencecases-degrades-performance) before.

Does anyone has any more charitable explanation of the observed behavior other than "it's a bug that should be reported to Wolfram Research"?

**Update.** Notice, in particular, that it's not the pattern matching that is slow - it's speedy:

```
zeros2[lst_] := 
 Cases[Partition[lst, 2, 1], {a_, b_} /; Sign[a[[2]]] != Sign[b[[2]]]]

With[{data = Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 5, 0.1}]}, 
 fastZeros[data] == zeros[data] == zeros2[data]]
(* True *)

zeros2[Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 200, 0.1}]] // 
  Length // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.004051, 64} *)
```

**Update.** Meanwhile, I've submitted `[CASE:4999270]`.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this is not a speed regression as far as I can tell. It was (alas) always this slow.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielLichtblau - you are right. I shouldn't call it a "regression" which presumes a deterioration of performance. I changed the title to reflect that.

Rather, it's an observation that a pretty useful function is not optimized for what seems to be a natural use case.

Comment: With `SeedRandom[0];
data = RandomInteger[1000, 2000];`,
Compare
`SequenceCases[data, {11, x_}] // AbsolutTiming`
versus
`SequenceCases[data, {11, x_} /; True] // AbsolutTiming` Seems to be a consequence of using `Condition`

Comment: Sure - but compare to `Cases[RandomInteger[100, {2000, 2}], {11, x_} /; True] // AbsoluteTiming`, which is instantaneous. So it's a combination of `SequenceCases` and `Condition` that somehow slows things down.

Comment: (@MichaelE2 bat me to this) I just noticed we have an open bug report to the effect that `Condition` can severely slow `SequenceCases`. Also using `Alternatives` causes a severe speed degradation as compared to two cases without alternatives.

Comment: I don't think `Cases` is comparable to `SequenceCases`.

Comment: What I meant to say is that the standalone `Condition` is pretty fast.

Comment: Jose Martin-Garcia informs me that there is [this related MSE thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83325/performance-problems-in-new-sequence-functions).

Comment: What I mean is that matching sequences is potentially complex, and `Condition` makes `SequenceCases` switch to an algorithm with bad time-complexity. Without `Condition`, `SequenceCases` analyzes the pattern `{11, x_}` and has an efficient algorithm it can choose. (All this is guesswork, btw. I assume `Condition` is taken as an sign of a "complex" pattern that is not worth analyzing.)

Comment: A reasonable guess, and we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: This example is now in a suggestion/bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 13.3.1, this particular performance issue is fixed:

[image]