# Why is SequencePosition or SequenceCases so slow on large lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I observed that SequencePosition or Sequence Cases on a list of around 60'000 digits is so slow that I had to sort out to string pattern matching.
Is this normal behavior or should Wolfram have a look at it?
Let me demonstrate it on the first 500 digits of Pi:

```
t = Flatten[RealDigits[N[Pi, 500]]]

SequencePosition[t, {3 .., 8 ..}] // Timing
{23.2813, {{18, 19}, {25, 27}, {26, 27}, {124, 125}, {171, 172}, {197, 198}, {383, 384}, {431, 432}, {489, 490}}}

ts = TextString[Row[t]];
StringPosition[ts, "3" .. ~~ "8" ..] // Timing
{0.015625, {{18, 19}, {25, 27}, {26, 27}, {124, 125}, {171, 172}, {197, 198}, {383, 384}, {431, 432}, {489, 490}}}
```

Many thanks for your thoughts.
Markus

Comment: About all I can say is this is a known limitation with an open suggestion report to improve on it.

Comment: Also see [83325](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83325/performance-problems-in-new-sequence-functions).

Comment: Still the same behavior in Version 14.