# Counting subsequences (i.e., patterns) within a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, sequence, counting

I would like to count the number of subsequences in list.  Say I have data given by:

```
data = {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1};
```

I would like to count the number times I see the following subsequences: `{1,1}, {1,2}, {2,1}, {2,2}`.  Is there a quick way to do so?  I've tried a few approaches using `Count` and `Cases` with no luck.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: very very closely related [941](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/941/5478). Also linked topics there from SO are quite important.

Comment: Do you mean a "sublist" or really a "subsequence"? The latter normally [doesn't have to be contiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) while I'd use the former (or "substring" in the case of strings) to refer to contiguous subsequences. In your example the difference doesn't matter, because all subsequences also appear as substrings, so it's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
data = {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1};
sub = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}};

Count[Partition[data, 2, 1], Alternatives @@ sub]
```

> ```
> 10
> ```

Or each separately:

```
Count[Partition[data, 2, 1], #] & /@ sub
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 3, 2}
> ```

---

More general, for different length subsequences:

```
Length[ReplaceList[data, {___, ##, ___} :> {}]] & @@@ sub
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 3, 2}
> ```

```
 Length[ReplaceList[data, {___, ##, ___} :> {}]] & @@@ {{1, 2, 1}, {1}}
```

> ```
> {2, 6}
> ```

Comment: A little shorter: `Tr @ ReplaceList[data, {___, ##, ___} :> 1] &`

Comment: Thank you very much Kuba! (Also, thanks to Mr. Wizard and ubpdqn.)

Answer (score 6):

String processing is often useful for these problems if it can be applied.

```
data = {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1};

pat = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}};

ts = ToString @ Row[#, ","] &;

StringCount[ts@data, ts /@ pat, Overlaps -> True]
```

> ```
> 10
> ```

Individually:

```
With[{ds = ts@data},
  StringCount[ds, ts@#, Overlaps -> True] & /@ pat
]
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 3, 2}
> ```

Or perhaps better:

```
StringCases[ts@data, ts@# -> # & /@ pat, Overlaps -> True] // Tally
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, 2}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{2, 1}, 3}, {{2, 2}, 2}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Another way with  **`ListCorrelate`** used with proper arguments, for example :

```
data = {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1};
sub = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}};

Total@Boole@
    ListCorrelate[#, data, {1, -1}, "paddingUselessHere", Equal, And] & /@ sub
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 3, 2}
> ```

#### Another example

Let's say you're just looking for the longer pattern `{1,2,1}` :

```
Total@Boole@ListCorrelate[{1, 2, 1}, data, {1, -1}, "paddingUselessHere", Equal, And]
```

> 2

#### Explanation

It is easy to understand what [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate.html) does with this example :

```
ListCorrelate[{p1, p2}, {a, b, c, d}, {1, -1}, "whatever", f, g]
```

> `{g[f[p1, a], f[p2, b]], g[f[p1, b], f[p2, c]], g[f[p1, c], f[p2, d]]}`

*(When the 4th argument of ListCorrelate is `{1,-1}` (default value), the 5th argument (padding) is useless, that's why i set it to "whatever".)*

Answer (score 3):

I post this just for fun (I have voted for Kuba's answer):

```
data = {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1};
targ = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}};
Join@@(Last@Reap[Sow[1, #] & /@ (w @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1]), 
  w @@@ targ, #1 /. w[a__] -> List[a] -> Total@#2 &])
```

w just used as a wrapper for tagging.

yields:

```
(* {{1, 1} -> 2, {1, 2} -> 3, {2, 1} -> 3, {2, 2} -> 2}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Version 10.1 introduces [`SequencePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html), [`SequenceCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html), and [`SequenceCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCount.html).

> **SequenceCount[*list*, *sub*]**
> gives a count of the number of times *sub* appears as a sublist of *list*.
>
> **SequenceCount[*list*, *patt*]**
> gives the number of sublists in *list* that match the general sequence pattern *patt*.

All three functions take the [`Overlaps`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlaps.html) option:

> - With the default option setting `Overlaps -> False`, `SequenceCount` includes only sublists that do not overlap. With the setting `Overlaps -> True`, it includes sublists that overlap.
> - With `Overlaps -> All`, multiple sublists that match the same pattern are all included.  With `Overlaps -> True`, only the first such matching sublist at a given position is included.

```
data = {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1};

pat = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}};

SequenceCount[data, #, Overlaps -> True] & /@ pat

Thread[pat -> %]
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 3, 2}
>
> {{1, 1} -> 2, {1, 2} -> 3, {2, 1} -> 3, {2, 2} -> 2}
> ```

Before using these functions you may wish to see:

- [Performance problems in new Sequence functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83325/121)

Answer (score 2):

**Using the 6-argument form of `Partition`:**

```
ClearAll[countF]
countF[x_, y_] := Total @ Partition[x, 2, 1, 1, {}, Boole[MemberQ[y, {##}]] &]

data = {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1};
sub = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}};

countF[data, sub]
```

> 10

```
countF[data, Most @ Rest @ sub]
```

> 6

**Using `BlockMap`:**

```
ClearAll[countF2]
countF2[x_, y_] := Total @ BlockMap[Boole[MemberQ[y, #]]&, x, 2, 1]

countF2[data, sub]
```

> 10

```
countF2[data, Most @ Rest @ sub]
```

> 6

Answer (score 2):

Another version using [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate), that should be much faster for large lists:

```
(* define inverse pattern *)
Table[
    pattern[{2, 1} . pat] = pat,
    {pat, {{1,1}, {1,2}, {2,1}, {2,2}}}
];

(* use ListCorrelate and fix keys *)
KeyMap[pattern] @ Counts @ ListCorrelate[{2,1},{1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1}]

Values @ %
```

> <|{1, 1} -> 2, {1, 2} -> 3, {2, 1} -> 3, {2, 2} -> 2|>
>
> {2, 3, 3, 2}

Here is an example with a longer data list:

```
data = RandomInteger[{1, 2}, 10^6];
KeySort @ KeyMap[pattern] @ Counts @ ListCorrelate[{2, 1}, data] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.012973, <|{1, 1} -> 250799, {1, 2} -> 249508, {2, 1} -> 249509, {2, 2} -> 
>      250183|>}

By my testing, this answer is at least 2 orders of magnitude faster than the others.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1};
```

Using `Counts` in tandem with `SequenceCases`

```
Counts @ SequenceCases[list, {_, _}, Overlaps -> True]
```

[image]

```
Total[%]
```

10

```
Keys[%%]
```

{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1};
subseqs = Subsequences[list, {2}];

seqscount = Association[Reap[Sow[_, subseqs], _, Rule[#1, Length@#2] &][[2]]]

(*<|{1, 1} -> 2, {1, 2} -> 3, {2, 1} -> 3, {2, 2} -> 2|>*)

Total@seqscount

(*10*)
```