# How to locate a list within a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, coefficients

for example `f[{1,2,3,4},{2,3}]=True`, `f[{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4}]=True` but `f[{1,2,3,4},{2,4}]=False`. Which function should I use because I don't want to reinvent the wheel.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the result of `f[{1,2,3,4},{3,2}]`?

Comment: `SequencePosition[##]!={}&`?

Comment: Related: [(941)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/941/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We may use pattern matching:

```
f[a_, {ss__}] := MatchQ[a, {___, ss, ___}]
```

Testing:

```
f[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3}]          (* True  *)
f[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}]       (* True  *)
f[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4}]          (* False *)
```

This should work in any version of *Mathematica* and it is nearly equivalent in performance to [`SequencePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html): (as measured in version 10.1 under Windows)

```
f1[Range[10000], {5000, 5001, 5002}] // RepeatedTiming
f[Range[10000], {5000, 5001, 5002}]  // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.000444, True}
>
> {0.000475, True}

Comment: great! neat and simple

Answer (score 8):

It really depends on how fast you need it and how many elements your list will have. Let's assume the worst:

```
list = Range[1000000];
contain = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

Checking `fun` from Lotus

```
fun[list, contain] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.27, True} *)
```

and `f` from kglr

```
f[list, contain] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.043, True} *)
```

Here is a version that is again an order of magnitude faster, although it looks awful

```
h[list_, sub_] := With[{l = Length[sub]},
  Catch[Developer`PartitionMap[If[# === sub, Throw[True]] &, list, l, 1]] === True
  ]

h[list, contain] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.00271, True} *)
```

### However

As you see, my example was made to test the influence of a large input list and an early accepting `contain`. I should note when `contain` is located at the far end of `list`, @kglr's version works best and it seems to have a constant running time.

### Final notes

I tried to find a simple algorithm, that matches the speed of `SequencePosition` and is in most cases better. A satisfactory solution seems to be to go linear through the list and test if the current element is equal to the first element in the `sub` list. Only if yes, we compare the full sublist.

In high-level Mathematica, this still cannot compete but when we compile it down to C, then this seems to be a fast solution. A clear disadvantage of this solution is that it only works with typed lists (here integers).

```
uglyC = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}, {sub, _Integer, 1}},
  With[{l = Length[sub], first = sub[[1]]},
   Do[
     If[list[[i]] === first && 
       list[[i ;; i + Length[sub] - 1]] === sub,
      Return[True]
      ], {i, 1, Length[list] - Length[sub] + 1}
     ] === True
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ]
```

Let's do some test-cases with a random large list

```
list = RandomInteger[100, 1000000];
```

First we try a long sublist that is not part. I need to use `AbsoluteTiming` for the compiled code to get meaningful results

```
f[list, Range[50, 150]] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0057, False} *)

Median@Table[First@AbsoluteTiming[uglyC[list, Range[50, 150]]], {50}]
(* 0.004662 *)
```

Sublists that match, but were the match is at the very end of `list` will have an equivalent runtime. However, the closer the match comes to the front of `list`, the faster the `Do` loop will be

```
f[list, list[[100 ;; 110]]] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0057, True} *)

Median@Table[First@AbsoluteTiming[uglyC[list, list[[100 ;; 110]]]], {50}]
(* 5.*10^-6 *)
```

I have not tested all scenarios and I believe the ugly compiled code should not be used, if it is not absolutely time-critical. A simple `SequencePosition` should be preferred.

Comment: On my machine, kglr's `f2` seems to be significantly slower than `f1`. I think it's also important to examine a negative case, such as `{889, 893, 894, 895}`. `h`'s construction seems like it would have quite a bit of difficulty getting `False` results quickly.

Comment: @eyorble Yes, that was what I tried to express in my last section. All mapping methods check each sublist and the worst case is when the sublist is not in the original list. For this case, kglr's approach still works fast while all others drop like hell. A fast solution could theoretically be done in a `Do` loop, but I don't get this fast enough (not without compiling at least).

Answer (score 7):

```
f1 = SequencePosition[##] != {}&;
f1b = Length[SequencePosition[##]] > 0&; (* thanks: @Henrik Schumacher *)

f1[{1, 2, 3, 4}, #] & /@ {{2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 4},{2, 3, 1}}
```

> {True, True, False, False}

```
f2 = MemberQ[Subsequences[#, {Length @ #2}],#2]&;
f2[{1, 2, 3, 4},#] & /@ {{2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 3, 1}}
```

> {True, True, False, False}

Two variations on halirutan's approach:

```
ClearAll[f3,f4]
f3[lst_,sub_]:= Or @@ BlockMap[# === sub&, lst, Length@sub, 1]
f4[lst_,sub_]:=Catch[BlockMap[If[# === sub, Throw[True]]&, lst, Length@sub, 1]] === True
```

Comment: It is often a bit more efficient testing lists for length `>0` instead of comparing agains `{}`. `Length[SequencePosition[##]] > 0 &` should be a bit faster than `f1`.

Comment: Nice, now we have cyclic references between our posts :) I still like your `SequencePosition` best. It's clear, short and should work for a wide range of cases. +1

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, thank you, great point. I added that variant.

Answer (score 4):

How about this ?

```
fun[list1_, list2_] := Module[{n, list3},
  n = Length[list2];
  list3 = Partition[list1, n, 1];
  MemberQ[list3, list2]
  ]

In[10]:= fun[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3}]

Out[10]= True

In[8]:= fun[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}]

Out[8]= True

In[9]:= fun[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4}]

Out[9]= False
```