# Built-in function to know if a list is inside another?

Tags: function-construction, built-in-symbols

For example, if the function is `f[a_List,b_List]` then in `f[{a,b,c},{a,b}]` and `f[{a,b,c},{b,c}]` should return true but false in `f[{a,b,c},{c,b}]` or `f[{a,b,c},{a,c}]`.

Any built in functions that do this, or a fast workaround?

An ugly way to do it is

`And@@Table[MemberQ[b,a[[i]]],{i,Length@a}]`

but I'm looking for a better or built-in function.

Comment: closely related  / possible duplicate q/a: [How to locate a list within a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174178/125)

Comment: What about `SubsetQ`?